# Can I create dynamically automation from smart contract using Gelato Automate?

Tags: blockchain, automate, gelato, cron-jobs

Can I initiate new Gelato automation schedules from a contract?
Like call some on-chain API saying "please start calling this address periodically, here's payment for the next month"?